# git checkout -- file changes permissions for existing file

Tags: permissions, git

When I edit a file, and then want to undo my changes, I use

```
git checkout -- file.txt
```

the problem is that `git` does not keep the file permissions of the existing file. `file.txt` has permissions `644`, but after `git checkout` it has `600` (which I think comes from my `umask`)

I know git does not store file permissions, and I am not expecting to remember permissions when creating new file.

But in this case the file exists.Why can't `git` keep the permissions as they are?

Could this be solved with some ugly hack (some hook) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Git checks out files, it by default uses the umask of the file on the system, setting the executable bit if it's a directory or it's marked as an executable file.  That's because Git removes and re-creates the file, so it doesn't preserve the permissions of the existing file.

This is actually by design, because there's an option, `core.sharedRepository`, that lets you configure the permissions of files to be checked out.  By default, it is set to `umask`, which means to use your umask.  If you want different behavior in your repository, you can set it differently, such as to `0644`, which will use that value.

It is possible to use a `post-checkout` hook to change the permissions back if you want, although this may not work in all cases.

Comment: thanks. So how can I use a `post-checkout` hook to change the permissions back?

Comment: You write a shell script to do that, make it executable, and put it in `.git/hooks/post-checkout`.  See `githooks(5)`.

Comment: can you please give me working example of such script?

Comment: It can be as simple as a shell script which runs `chmod 644 file.txt`.

Comment: - that will not work. I need to keep the permissions as they were before i executed git checkout. These may have been `644` or completely different.

Comment: That's not possible with Git.  It may remove files without regard to their old state any time you do a checkout and doesn't care about their old permissions.  If you need files to have a specific set of permissions, store them under a different name and copy them into place with a script that preserves permissions.

Comment: but that was the whole point of my original question! I wanted to keep the permissions, after executing git checkout.