# Is it necessary to set the executable bit on scripts checked out from a git repo?

Tags: permissions, git

I have some scripts in a folder that I run often. These scripts are updated frequently. To be more specific, every time we do a deployment on our server, we replace the scripts with updated ones from our git repo.

Do we have to make them executable every time?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621738/git-checkout-file-changes-permissions-for-existing-file

Comment: Git is not a deployment tool. While Git does support preserving an execution bit on a tracked file, you should be using some other tool that takes a Git repository (or some artifacts produced by build tool from a Git repository) and installs files where needed.

Comment: @dr_ thank you very much!

Comment: @chepner I wouldn't get overly caught up on that though. Depending on context there may be no good reason to spend the time / money setting up a CD tool.  Git is ultimately a versioning and distribution tool.  When you're managing 10, 100 or 1,000 servers then CD tools are really powerful.  When you are managing just 1 and want to version some scripts on it, then you won't see any real value from a full blown CD pipeline.

Comment: Just because you aren't using *continuous* delivery doesn't mean you can't logically separate your source management from your build process from your deployment process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are simply checking out from git, you should be able to set the executable mode flag on the files in git itself.

If you are committing from *Nix (including macOS) then you can usually¹ just `chmod +x` the file before you `git add` `git commit`.

If you are committing from somewhere that doesn't have an executable bit, or perhaps from Windows, see [the answer to *How to create file execute mode permissions in Git on Windows?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21694391/453851).

This should result in the files having executable mode set on them as they are updated by git during a `git pull` or `git checkout` etc.

---

¹Note this can only work if you've cloned onto a filesystem that stores the executable bit `+x` and has been mounted in a way that allows it; some filesystems might not, such as NTFS or FAT32.